# Microsoft CRM 2011 dynamic sitemap

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to have CRM's left hand navigation change dynamically?  I am envisioning a customization where a user can 'save' a search and have it appear as a *subarea* link on the left hand navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could programmatically export the sitemap, insert the node you want, then reimport it and publish it. The user would have to refresh the page to see the change, however, and this would be at the organization level, so it's not like the user would see their own personalized sitemap.

Other than that, I don't think there's another supported way to make changes to the sitemap on the fly. There's probably some trickery you could do with an HTTP Module and some javascript though.

Also, if the user is saving Advanced Find results or their own filtered searches through the native UI, those are available in the flyout menu for that particular entity automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on how to display views from the side navigation. I managed to get the views loaded, but crm2011 would go into an infinite loop (and load itself within itself) and eventually crash the browser. So trying to load views from the side is a no go from what I've seen.

You could potentially disable and enable access to the side items via security (through the SDK) but I doubt you could let the user dynamically update that side panel.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't export the solution and then import it dynamically in this situation because it would reflect for all users.

You could put place holders inside the existing sitemap and then display them for the user with custom JavaScript.  You'd also need to point to the specific user's link on the fly too.

The only real problem I can see is getting the JavaScript to fire.  If it's an on-premise solution you could probably do it, but an update might turn it off.

I think you are better off doing a custom button like this from the Ribbon.  You could create a fancy pull down menu or nice little pop-up.